# Deploy more than two developer applications on a windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am sure I'm not the first one asking this question, but I didn't found anything so I created a new question:

Is it somehow possible to avoid this limit or some way to expand it?
I really want to develop more applications for my Windows Phone without deleting older apps I made.

TL;DR I have deployed the maximum of dev-apps on my phone, but I want more. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of 2 side loaded apps is only present if your phone was developer-unlocked via the App Studio program.

If you purchase a Windows Phone Developer Account ($19 via dev.windowsphone.com) then you can developer unlock up to 3 phones, each phone can then have up to 10 side-loaded apps for development testing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I did not know that you have to pay, only to get more "slots" for dev apps... Anyway, I will now put some apps in the store :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do so. The limit is there because you should use it only to TEST your apps, not to keep them on the device forever. I'm sure that the limit is not 2 apps, though, I have 5 or 6 apps installed on my device without a problem.

To have more of your own apps installed on a device, there is just one way: submit them to the Windows Store, download them on your own device, (leave a 5-star rating:),) uninstall the dev app from your local device. Of course, you can't debug this app because the Phone treats the store app and the app Visual Studio can deploy as two different apps, so as soon as you want to debug the app, it will be on your device twice.